# radiobutton checked property is always false when control.find(id) is used to find dynamically generated radio button

Tags: asp.net

i have dynamically added radio button to webform as shown below. 
On submit click when i try to find the radio check property using control.find(radiobuttonid). It always return false even when radio button is checked. can some body help me how to do it?

```
                        RadioButton r1 = new RadioButton();
                        r1.ID = "r1" + i.ToString();
                        r1.GroupName = "radio";
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(r1);
                        Label t1 = new Label();
                        t1.ID = "t1" + i.ToString();
                        t1.Text = ReturnCode["ans1"].ToString();
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(t1);
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(
         new LiteralControl("\r\n<br /> \r\n"));
                        RadioButton r2 = new RadioButton();
                        r2.GroupName = "radio";
                        r2.ID = "r2" + i.ToString();
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(r2);
                        Label t2 = new Label();
                        t2.ID = "t2" + i.ToString();
                        t2.Text = ReturnCode["ans2"].ToString();
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(t2);
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(
         new LiteralControl("\r\n<br /> \r\n"));

                        RadioButton r3 = new RadioButton();
                        r3.ID = "r3" + i.ToString();
                        r3.GroupName = "radio";
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(r3);

                        Label t3 = new Label();
                        t3.ID = "t3" + i.ToString();
                        t3.Text = ReturnCode["ans3"].ToString();
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(t3);
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(
         new LiteralControl("\r\n<br /> \r\n"));
                        RadioButton r4 = new RadioButton();
                        r4.ID = "r4" + i.ToString();
                        r4.GroupName = "radio";
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(r4);
                        Label t4 = new Label();
                        t4.ID = "t4" + i.ToString();
                        t4.Text = ReturnCode["ans3"].ToString();
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(t4);
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(
      new LiteralControl("\r\n<br /> \r\n"));
```

Comment: Show the design code of your radio button.

Comment: Probably this article: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110205-1.aspx will help.

Comment: I think you should use the following way to find the value of dynamically generated control.
http://dotnetsolutionsbyankit.blogspot.in/2013/05/find-dynamic-generated-controls-from.html

Comment: Please find above only that is the code i have for radio button :@AishvaryaKarthik